# How to iterate over multiple dataframe rows at the same time in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

How to iterate over multiple dataframe  rows at the same time in pandas
df1,df2

```
for index1 row1 in df1.iterrows():
 for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
```

i want to use one for loop instead of two for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for that

```
for (index_1, row_1), (index_2, row_2) in zip(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows()):
    ...
```

Although there is a very high chance you don't need this loop at all but instead use pandas-native operations to deal with the frames.